Выпадающий список атрибутов с картинкой
Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой: на сайте есть товар с атрибутами и пользователь может выбрать определенную конфигурацию. Вот пример:

но мне нужно, чтобы слева от текста в каждом пункте меню выводилась картинка, то бишь должно выглядеть вот так: 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, плагин для этого, или может как-то хитроумно надо поменять код)
Тема Flatsome установлена.
Заранее спасибо!
